# Refresh multiple Excel files with different file paths - Using Python

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Hi I have just started learning python/programming and have the following problem:

I want to refresh several excel files with python. However, all these excel files have a completely different file path, so they are not all stored in one folder.

Using `pypiwin32` it was no problem to write a code that refreshes one excel file. To refresh several excel files with different file paths, currently I solved it this way:

```
import win32com.client as win32

Xlsx = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = False
Xlsx.Visible = False

book1 = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open('<path_to_excel_workbook1>')
book2 = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open('<path_to_excel_workbook2>')


book1.RefreshAll()
book2.RefreshAll()

Xlsx.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

book1.Save()
book2.Save()

book1.Close(SaveChanges=True)
book2.Close(SaveChanges=True)

Xlsx.Quit()

del book1
del book2
del Xlsx
```

However, the entire code becomes unnecessarily long when there are 50 or more Excel files to be updated.
Is there a way to iterate through all Excel files, without writing a line of code for every Excel file to execute `RefreshAll()`,`Save()` and `Close()`?
Maybe by using a loop or similiar solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that.

```
import win32com.client as win32

file_paths = ['path_one', 'path_two']

Xlsx = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = False
Xlsx.Visible = False

for path in file_paths:
    book = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open(path)
    book.RefreshAll()
    Xlsx.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    book.Close(SaveChanges=True)

Xlsx.Quit()
```

Comment: As noted @el_oso you can to extract code from loop to function for using this code in other places

Answer (score 0):

you want to make a re-useable function that takes in a filepath and Xlsx object. You can then make a simple loop over all the paths in a list

```py
def refresh_excel(Xlsx, filepath):
    #everything under this indented code block is run every time you call refresh_excel
    workbook = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    workbook.RefreshAll()
    workbook.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    workbook.Save()
    workbook.Close() #this might not be needed
    return True

#this unindented block sets up you Excel application and stores your list of excel filepaths you want to refresh
Xlsx = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = False
Xlsx.Visible = False

file_list = ['path1.xlsx', 'path2.xlsx', 'path3.xlsx']
#create a loop that runs refresh_excel function, using every filename in your list. 
#The Xlsx parameter ensures that you use the same Excel application, 
#which would help speed up your script by not needlessly opening and 
#closing a new Excel application for every file.
for file in file_list:
   refresh_excel(Xlsx, file)

Xlsx.Quit()
```

The only real benefit you get from creating a function, indicated by the `def` keyword is that *if* your script grows, gets more complicated and is doing more that one thing it helps keep things organised instead of having to try and debug 100's of lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when I try this code out I get an error message: `xl` is not defined.
It would be very helpful, if you could explain what `xl` and `f` is used for in this code. 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: corrected the 'xl' typo and improved the name of f.